# Can't set PHP Interface function - Why?

Tags: php, interface

I'm trying to set the "setFlyBhavior(FlyBehavior $newFlyBehavior)" dynamically. Can anyone explain why it will not work in the code below? I appreciate your help.

```
<?php

abstract class Duck {
   public $flyBehavior;
   public function performFly() {
        return $this->flyBehavior->fly(); 
    }

    public function setFlyBhavior(FlyBehavior $newFlyBehavior) {
        $this->flyBehavior = $newFlyBehavior;  
    }       
}

interface FlyBehavior {
    public function fly();
}

class GotWings implements FlyBehavior {
    public function fly(){
        return "<br />I'm flying with wings!!<br />";     
    }
}

class NotWings implements FlyBehavior {
   public function fly(){
        return "<br />I can't fly I have no wings!!<br />";    
   } 
}

class FlyingDuck extends Duck {      
   public function __construct(){   
        $this->flyBehavior = new GotWings();  
   }  
}
        $ducky = new FlyingDuck();
       // Code works when the setFlyBehavior function is commented out. 
       $ducky->setFlyBehavior(new NoWings);     
       echo "<br />I'm a Duck: " . $ducky->performFly();    
?>
```

Note: The code works when not calling the "ducky->setFlyBehavior function. I also tried defining the setFlyBehavior function in the Duck class without using type casting, which also failed e.g.

```
public function setFlyBhavior($newFlyBehavior) {
        $this->flyBehavior = $newFlyBehavior;
}
```

Comment: Failed/didn't work how? What'd you expect, what happened instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the wrong function and class names.

Replace the line:

```
$ducky->setFlyBehavior(new NoWings);
```

With:

```
$ducky->setFlyBhavior(new NotWings);
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have condense my code so it could be viewed without scrolling. Please explain what function I should be calling. The setFlyBehavior function is being inherited by the NoWings class. I used the interface for loose coupling. It seems that I should be able to call the setFlyBehavior function to give the flyBehavior variable a new value. Please expain in more detail where you feel I am going wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: there is not anything wrong with the code except that, within your abstract class, you have defined your function as `setFlyBhavior` but you are calling it as `setFlyBehavior` after you create an object, hence you have created one of your classes as `NotWings` but you are calling it as `NoWings` same again after creating your `$ducky` object. Thats why your code is not working. Replace `$ducky->setFlyBehavior(new NoWings); ` line with `$ducky->setFlyBhavior(new NotWings); ` then you are fine.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that typo out. It should be "NoWings". Thank you for taking the time to help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Dont miss the `setFlyBhavior` also.

Comment: Burak, until I can develop an eye for erroneous syntax as a beginner is there a way to troubleshoot similar errors using some type of platform? I'm using a simple text editor for coding. Also I will tag your answer. Again thank you much!

Comment: Use an advanced ide, such as PHPStorm or Sublimetext I'd recommend.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice Burak. Wishing you the best.